# Android AddMarker stop working today

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have problem with my apps, 2 weeks ago apps working. Today stop... Google Maps loading but dont addMarkers and dont getlatlong. I try everyting. Here is my code:

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    lm = (LocationManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); // <5>
    if (location != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        this.onLocationChanged(location); // <6>
    }
    }
```

I add marker like that:

```
    Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("title")
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng)));
```

I dont know why that stop working.;/ In manifest i got all permission.

Comment: firstly, post the log pls.

Comment: App dont crash. Just stop show marker... http://postimg.org/image/lbcv0ywuz/  . It is strange. I have not done any changes. Now i get error Service not available

Comment: Two exceptions can be seen in the pic, `IOException:Service not Available` when `getFromLocationName`,  **NullPointerException** in `onLocationChanged` at line 603. Check this line pls.  BTY, did you enable your location service??

Comment: could you post the code in `onLocationChanged` pls?

Comment: I comment that metod now i dont need and i still get Service not Available so i think that is the problem but how solved that?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/5x5txdpgr/ . pokazAdres :  List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(onLongClicklat,
     onLongClicklng, 1);

Comment: maybe other location based APPs also don't work normally ? how about reboot your device ?